# How to remove blank space between banner and top of page

Tags: css

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href=".\favicon.ico">
        <title>rentPRO</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="top_menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Fleet</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
            <div id="footer">© rentPRO 2015</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background-image: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bBxOrYzmzQE/VM57QXCUoEI/AAAAAAAAAGg/WSUG7fe2ekE/w1024-h190-no/port-louis-capital-city-picture-courtesy-mauritius-tourism-promotion-authority_gallery_small.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#top_menu {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font: bold 16px Tahoma;
    height: 40px;
    width: 1075px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-color: black;
}
```

The `height: 40px;` is making the banner to come down by 40px, thus leaving a blank space between the top of the page and the banner. When I remove this line, the problem goes away but the navigation bar no more has a background. Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Providing the HTML code that goes along with this would give more insight into the problem.

Comment: On `#top_menu`, what is the purpose of `top: 200px;`?

Comment: to make the nav bar appear just below the banner(which is 190px)

Comment: @JolanGoburdhun change the `top: 190px;` and check

Comment: I think you want `#top_menu` to appear before `#header` in the code, but you want `#header` to appear above `#top_menu` on the rendered page. Is that correct?

Comment: @JPrakash it doesn't work

Comment: @showdev even if #header appears before #top_menu in the code, it is not a problem for me, but yes i want the #header to appear before #top_menu on the page

Comment: Is the margin of your body set to 0px?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to put your `<nav>`tag inside the `div` with id header.
Set `top: 190px;` in #top_menu.

**HTML :**

```
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href=".\favicon.ico">
        <title>rentPRO</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <nav id="top_menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Fleet</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
            <div id="footer">© rentPRO 2015</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
    background-image: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bBxOrYzmzQE/VM57QXCUoEI/AAAAAAAAAGg/WSUG7fe2ekE/w1024-h190-no/port-louis-capital-city-picture-courtesy-mauritius-tourism-promotion-authority_gallery_small.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#top_menu {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top: 190px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font: bold 16px Tahoma;
    height: 40px;
    width: 1075px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-color: black;
}
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cx9kgzwa/)

Comment: The menu contents overflows the boundaries of `#top_menu`, which does not seem desirable.

Comment: I have created this fiddle from the provided css and css of menu are not required for answer thats why I leave them .

Comment: Fair enough, but `#content` and `#footer` also appear to be hidden using this structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the order of elements in your HTML, the simplest solution is to insert `#top_menu` between `#header` and `#content`. This structure more accurately reflects the structure you want to display and the elements will flow naturally. You can remove `height` and `top` from `#top_menu`.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <nav id="top_menu"> ... </nav>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div id="footer">© rentPRO 2015</div>
</div>
```

Example below:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  background-image: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bBxOrYzmzQE/VM57QXCUoEI/AAAAAAAAAGg/WSUG7fe2ekE/w1024-h190-no/port-louis-capital-city-picture-courtesy-mauritius-tourism-promotion-authority_gallery_small.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#top_menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  font: bold 16px Tahoma;
  width: 1075px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <nav id="top_menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Fleet</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div id="footer">© rentPRO 2015</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, i moved your header tag above your menu, took away the height and changed the top menu height to 20.

```
 </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header"></div>

        <nav id="top_menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Fleet</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <div class="content">
            </div>
            <div id="footer">© rentPRO 2015</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

#header {
    background-image: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bBxOrYzmzQE/VM57QXCUoEI/AAAAAAAAAGg/WSUG7fe2ekE/w1024-h190-no/port-louis-capital-city-picture-courtesy-mauritius-tourism-promotion-authority_gallery_small.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#top_menu {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font: bold 16px Tahoma;

    width: 1075px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: The footer seems to get hidden behind `#top_menu`, which does not seem desirable.

Answer (score 0):

It would help you:

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
#banner {
    background-image: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bBxOrYzmzQE/VM57QXCUoEI/AAAAAAAAAGg/WSUG7fe2ekE/w1024-h190-no/port-louis-capital-city-picture-courtesy-mauritius-tourism-promotion-authority_gallery_small.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
#top_menu {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    /*top: 200px;*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font: bold 16px Tahoma;
    height: 40px;
    width: 1075px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-color: black;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="banner">
    </div>
    <nav id="top_menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Fleet</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
      <div id="footer">© rentPRO 2015</div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What have you changed to solve the issue?

Comment: I change the distribution of HTML. That's HTML5 snippets and in order of apparence so you don`t need position relative for position one element after other because in your HTML now is better. (Sorry about my english)